# console.log() not returning logical test without using parenthesis ()

Tags: javascript, undefined-behavior

Today while trying logging and testing conditions i came across following scenario with Chome console. Can someone help me understand why exactly this behavior.

```
// 1. in this output "this is not good" is not there and returned is false then 
// undefined ?? is that returned value
console.log("this is not good = " + 100 > 0 )
false
undefined
// 2. next case is executing fine by introducing ()... 
// undefined ?? return type
console.log("this is not good = " + (100 > 0) )
this is not good = true
undefined
```

Comment: kamituel's answer is correct.  Operator precedence explains how and why the parentheses change the behavior.  As to the `undefined` result, the console reports the value of an expression entered into it.  (If you entered `2 + 2`, it would return `4`.)  `console.log` has no return value, so, although it does print something to the display, when it returns, the `undefined` value is what's displayed.

Comment: Hey thanks... i think sometimes its nice to have a cup of coffee ... :)... not sure why i just could not figured this out in the first place... LOL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in operator precedence. 'Plus' operator (+) has higher priority than >.

So your first log is intepreted as follows:

```
console.log((this is not good = " + 100) > 0);
```

In the first step JS interpeter will concatenate string and "100".

See this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal behaviour.

1) When you evaluate

```
"this is not good = " + 100 > 0
```

you will evaluate:

```
"this is not good = 100" > 0
```

It's obviously `false`, so `false` will be printed.

2) When you evaluate

```
"this is not good = " + (100 > 0)
```

you will evaluate

```
"this is not good = " + true
```

It will just print the string.

Bonus) And for the `undefined`, that's the return valuse of `console.log()`. It's always `undefined` for this function.

Answer (score 0):

Because Javascript is executing the operations in the order you have specified.

```
"this is not good = " + 100
```

will result in

```
this is not good = 100
```

and then

```
"this is not good = + 100" > 0
```

will be false, because a String is not greater than zero.

---

In your flow, the first variable is a String, and the `+` (Addition operator) will try to concat two Strings. Then `100` will be cast in `"100"` and added.

If you use parenthesis instead, the mathematical operation will be executed (because the first variable will be `100`, a number) and the result `false` will be returned, cast to a String `"false"` and then added to your first String variable.